# Conditional Operator Query in C

Tags: c

```
{

   int i=0;

   int j;

   j=(i=0)?2:3;

   printf("the answer is %d",j);

}
```

I want to know why this statement `j=(i=0)?2:3;` gives the answer `3` when the value define to `i` is zero?

Comment: Try `i==0` instead of `i=0`.

Comment: @barakmanos Speak for yourself...

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: Why?

Comment: @barakmanos 1. Perhaps the OP intended to ask a question related to the result of the assignment operator, meaning your suggestion to replace the assignment operator with the comparison operator would render the question nonsense. 2. Did you *try it* yourself? It seems contradictory to tell others to try something when you haven't... and *if you had* tried this yourself, then you would know that using `==` in place of `=` here *makes no difference to the behaviour of the program*!

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour You have just provided evidence that you have not tried it yourself, because it does make a difference :-) As in, `i==0` evaluates to true, `i=0` evaluates to false.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: 1. OP asks (and I quote): "why this statement gives the answer `3` when the value define to `i` is zero". I figured that the implicit question was why this statement didn't give `2`, so by pointing this out, I was just trying to answer that (implicit) question.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: 2. You know what? You're absolutely right, I did not try it out myself, because I was so (arrogantly) sure of it. Now reading the **emphasized** part of your comment about `==` not making any difference, I thought "well, maybe I've got it all wrong and I should go back to first year"... So I gave it a try, what else could I do? I'm not that arrogant after all. Turns it **you** haven't tried it out yourself. Check yourself out before preaching to others, and think twice next time you aim the word *nonsense* at others (and then write a whole bunch of nonsense yourself)!!!

Comment: @barakmanos Yeh, my bad. [I'm so arrogant.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30815996/conditional-operator-query-in-c?noredirect=1#comment49679651_30815996) In case you missed it the first time (and the second time): I was wrong. My bad. The first point still stands, though...

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: No need to apologize, we all get arrogant sometimes, it's just that your statement `"It seems contradictory to tell others to try something when you haven't"` seems rather ridiculous (unless you were aiming it at yourself). Also, please read my comment about your first point. Although OP possibly wanted to use `i=0` in the conditional statement (highly unlikely, but still possible), his question strongly implies that he didn't. "Why does this statement give `3`" is another way of asking "why does it not give `2`", which is what I tried to answer on my original comment.

Comment: it should be noted that only typing a single '=' rather than '==' is a common mistake.   That mistake can be very difficult to debug.   That is why placing the literal on the left is so nice, as the compiler will catch it on the very first compile try.

Answer (score 5):

In C, zero is considered as false and all non-zero numbers are considered as true. This:

```
j=(i=0)?2:3;
```

is the same as

```
if(i = 0)
    j = 2;
else
    j = 3;
```

Here, `i = 0` assigns 0 to `i` and since 0 is considered as false, the else executes, assigning 3 to `j`.

---

Do note that `=` is the assignment operator and assigns its left and right operands. This is different from the conditional operator `==` which compares both its operands and returns 0 if false and 1 if true.

---

If you meant `==`, then `j=(i==0)?2:3;` is the same as

```
if(i == 0)
    j = 2;
else
    j = 3;
```

which will assign 2 to `j` as `i == 0` is true.

---

To prevent these kind of mistakes, you can use [Yoda Conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) [as suggested by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30815996/conditional-operator-query-in-c/30816010#comment49679472_30816010) [@JackWhiteIII](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2154149/jackwhiteiii), i.e , reversing the condition. For example,

```
j=(i=0)?2:3;
```

can be written as

```
j=(0=i)?2:3;
```

Since 0 is a constant value and cannot be altered, the compiler is emit an error, preventing these kind of mistakes. Note that both `0 == i` and `i == 0` do the same thing and both are indeed valid.

Comment: I think that adding "0 == i" would be a great help for the OP, as the compiler will then tell them that something is wrong.

Comment: @JackWhiteIII As hideous as the style may seem to you, what makes you think the OP didn't *intend* to nest that assignment into a conditional like that? I like this answer as it is, because it makes no assumptions.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Because the OP asked why he gets a 3 despite i being zero.

Comment: @JackWhiteIII , Added your suggestion into the answer.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Of course the output changes. Why don't you try it *yourself*?

Comment: @juanchopanza My bad. First point still stands, though. It's not valid to assume the OP didn't intend to ask about *the assignment operator* rather than *the comparison operator*... Nobody has asked "Hey, did you mean to *compare `i` to `0`*?", after all.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Agreed, although I'd bet my house in OP intending to use equality comparison.

Comment: @juanchopanza Don't bet your house... I might be in cahoots with the OP ;)

Answer (score 2):

`i=0` is an assignment. Use `i==0` for comparison.

Assignments return the new value of the variable that is being assigned to. In your case, that's `0`. Evaluated as a condition, that's false.

Answer (score 1):

As in the above code snippet,

```
{

   int i=0;

   int j;

   j=(i=0)?2:3;

   printf("the answer is %d",j);

}
```

you mistyped, (i==0) with (i=0) which just assigns 0 to i and checks the result, hence you're getting the output as, **the answer is 3**. The new code would be like,
{

```
   int i=0;

   int j;

   j=(i==0)?2:3;

   printf("the answer is %d",j);

}
```

The above corrected code snipped gives the output as,
**the answer is 2**.

Answer (score 0):

Because you mistyped the `==` operator.  You are setting `i` to the value `0` again and testing this value, which **is** 0, hence false.

Write this instead:

```
j = (i == 0) ? 2 : 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of **the assignment operator** (`=` in `i=0`) is the new value of the object (`0`). `0` is a false value, thus the 'false' branch of your condition is chosen, which is `3`.